# How to move layers around?

Tags: armature, bones

Probably a dumb question, but I can only find solutions on how to move bones from layer to layer,

not how to, for example, move a whole layer from slot 1 to slot 2.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way to move layers around from the UI.  I think the best you can do is select the source layer (either clicking in the properties panel or using the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> popup), use <kbd>A</kbd> to select all bones, and then <kbd>M</kbd>-ove them to the destination layer, assuming the destination layer is empty.  If you are trying to swap two layers "X" and "Y", you need to move all the bones in "X" to a spare empty layer "Z", then move "Y" to "X", and them move "Z" to "Y".